# Github: block PR based in other PR status

Tags: github, pull-request

Is there a way in [Github (Pull Request page)](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) to block some pull requests until another PR is merged?

#### Example:

1. Create a PR named *Test01*.
2. Create another PR named *Teste02*.

**Expected result:** The *Test02* must be only available to merge if the *Test01* is already merged. Otherwise, the Test02 can't be merged.